# Google Cloud Platform not checked[VMware Engine API]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vmware-vsphere

I want to use VMware Engine API on google platform, but I could not select the checkbox of the attached image [image: attached image].
How can I get the checkbox to be pressed?

I'm just getting started with GCP, so I don't know much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note: I meant to add this as a comment but my reputation does not permit me to do so. Thus I am adding this as an answer. Please let me know if I need to edit this answer.***

I have checked the screenshot you have shared. To me, you are trying to add quota for `VMware Engine API`, I am not familiar with the language thus may misunderstand this page/issue. I am assuming that you are also following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vmware-engine/docs/node-quota#requesting-quota) for `VMware Engine nodes` but you are not being able to select the appropriate region.

I would like to suggest you to try couple of things

- Can you click on the `EDIT QUOTAS` first then try to select the region you want to increase the quota
- Can you try with another browser to do the same to check if its browser dependent issue or not.

Furthermore,  please note that The Quotas page in the Cloud Console shows your Current usage and Limit as 0, even if your request to increase quota has been approved.

Comment: I'm not good at English, but thank you for your reply.
I used "Always Free Product" on GCP, but as a result of checking, it was not written in the document, but it seems that I can not request an increase during the Free Tier.